# How to set up REST API connection to pull records from databricks using Python

Tags: python, rest, databricks, mlflow

I'd like to upload and download mlflow experiments saved in databricks using python. I can set up the connection using the following code.

```
dbk_host = 'https://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.clooud.databricks.com'
api_version = '/api/2.0'
api_command = '/jobs/runs/list'
 
url = f"{dbk_host}{api_version}{api_command}"
DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN  }

response = requests.get(url = url, headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS, params={'limit': 25, 'offset': 0})
```

However, when I switched to a slightly different code, `400 Client Error` is reported.

```
dbk_host = 'https://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.clooud.databricks.com'
api_version = '/api/2.0'
api_command = '/mlflow/experiments/get-by-name'
 
url = f"{dbk_host}{api_version}{api_command}"
DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN  }
DBRKS_REQ_DATA = {"experiment_name": "mlflow-model-registry-example"}

response = requests.get(url = url, data=DBRKS_REQ_DATA, headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS)
```

Is it because I'm missing `params`? How should I solve this issue. And more generally, how should I set up connection, so that I can use the `REST API` as list.

https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#search-experiments

Comment: is it azure,aws or community databricks?

Comment: @JayashankarGS it's AWS.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to upload and download mlflow experiments saved in databricks

https://docs.databricks.com/mlflow/migrate-mlflow-objects.html

"To import or export MLflow objects to or from your Databricks workspace"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).